# Simple Objects and Constructor Issue

Tags: java, object, visibility, symbols

These are the instructions for the assignment:
In this task, you add four more methods to the APRectangle class and you define a static method that generates a string reporting the defining characteristics of a rectangle.

The first three methods — getTopRight, getBottomLeft, and getBottomRight — together with the accessor method getTopLeft return the APPoint objects that represent the four corners of the rectangle. As you define the three new methods, bear in mind that locations in a Java graphics window are described relative to the window's top left corner. So the further a location is to the right in a graphics window, the greater its x-coordinate. And — unexpectedly — the lower down a location is in a graphics window, the greater its y-coordinate. This means that the bottom corners of a rectangle will have greater y-coordinates than the top corners.

The fourth method, shrink, takes a single argument, the double d, and changes the width and the height of the rectangle to d% of their former values. So, for example, if the shrink method of an APRectangle r is called on the double 62.5, then r's width and height will be changed to 0.625 of their former values.

Finally, the static method printAPRectangle is such that, when its argument is the APRectangle whose top left corner is the APPoint with coordinate (-5.0,3.6), whose width is 7.5, and whose height is 6.3, it returns the string

"[APRectangle (-5.0,3.6) 7.5,6.3]"

As you define this method, pay close attention to the location of spaces. You will probably find it useful to call upon the printAPPoint static method as well as all three of the accessor methods of the APRectangle class.

The code I currently have is:

```
public class APRectangle 
{ 
  private APPoint myTopLeft; 
  private double  myWidth; 
  private double  myHeight; 

  public APRectangle( APPoint topLeft, double width, double height ) 
  { 
    // Code for the body of this constructor is hidden 
  } 

  /* 
   * Code for the accessor methods getTopLeft, getWidth, and getHeight and 
   * the modifier methods setTopLeft, setWidth, and setHeight is hidden 
   */ 
public String getTopRight()
 {
     APPoint myTopRight = new APPoint( myWidth + myTopLeft.getX(), myTopLeft.getY() );
     return myTopRight.printAPPoint();
 }
public String getBottomLeft()
 {
     APPoint myBottomLeft = new APPoint( myTopLeft.getX(), myTopLeft.getY()- myWidth );
     return myBottomLeft.printAPPoint();
 }
public String getBottomRight()
 {
     APPoint myBottomRight = new APPoint( myWidth + myTopLeft.getX(), myTopLeft.getY()- myWidth );
     return myBottomRight.printAPPoint();
 }
public double shrink(double d)
 {
     myWidth *= (d / 100.0);
     myHeight *= (d / 100.0);

 }
// Definitions of the APPoint class and the static method printAPPoint are hidden
 public String printAPRectangle()
  {
      return "[APRectangle " + getMyTopLeft() + " " + getMyWidth() + "," + getMyHeight() + "]" ;

  }
public static void main( String[] args )
{
  APRectangle r = new APRectangle( new APPoint( 25, 50 ), 30, 15 );
  System.out.println( printAPRectangle( r ) );
  System.out.println( "top right: " + printAPPoint( r.getTopRight() ) );
  System.out.println( "bottom left: " + printAPPoint( r.getBottomLeft() ) );
  System.out.println( "bottom right: " + printAPPoint( r.getBottomRight() ) );
  r.shrink( 80 );
  System.out.println( "shrunk to 80%: " + printAPRectangle( r ) );
}
```

I keep on receiving this error:

```
TC1.java:11 error: cannot find symbol
 return "[APRectangle " + getMyTopLeft() + " " + getMyWidth() + "," + getMyHeight() + "]" ;
```

If someone could please assist me (and a few others) in finding out what is wrong, I would be very grateful.  Thank you!

Comment: you are using getMyTopLeft() e.t.c, but your methods are named getTopLeft()...

Comment: Where do you even define getMyTopLeft() getMyWidth() or getMyHeight()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined any of the `getMy...` methods. (You have a `getTopLeft()`, but not `getMyTopLeft()`, etc.)

Since this is a method in the class, you might as well just use field references: `myTopLeft`, `myWidth`, and `myHeight`.

Comment: Within the body for APRectangle, the comment says that its hidden, so would I simply have to rewrite all of the code for it?  Because the website we're usuing shouldn't require that.  I'm sorry I cant just go and edit it right now because mclass period ended but ill get to it as quickly as possible.

Comment: @HitmarCurse - I don't understand your comment. The error is due to the indicated line of code referencing undefined methods. The comment names methods that do not match the method names used in the line with the error. Simply edit the line with the error to use the actual method names (`getWidth()` instead of `getMyWidth()`, etc.).